# Divide first and last column of a matrix by a number in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I divide first and last column of a matrix by a number in Matlab?
For example, I want to divide first and last column of matrix A by number 2:

```
 A=[1,2,3;4,5,6];
```

after dividing the answer is:

```
 B=[0.5,2,1.5;2,5,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight-forward approach would be to copy `A` to `B` and then grab the first and last columns of `B` and divide them by `2` and then re-assign the result to the first and last columns of `B`.

```
B = A;
B(:, [1 end]) = B(:, [1 end]) ./ 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
B = A;
B(:,1) = B(:,1)/2;
B(:,end) = B(:,end)/2;

B =

    0.5000    2.0000    1.5000
    2.0000    5.0000    3.0000
```